# Problems in debugging Django projects (Dev branch) in Pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm having a problem debugging Django (main/4.0.dev20210730183450) projects in Pycharm (2021 CE) and following is my config

[image: Pycharm Config]

**I can run (by clicking the run button) the project with no problem; Server runs fine and serves traffic. But I have problems *debugging* it.**

This the command generated by Pycharm

```
/home/cheng/Environments/proj1_env/bin/python3.8 /snap/pycharm-community/248/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 34965 --file /home/cheng/code/test_web/manage.py runserver
```

The error message is

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 212.4746.96)
/home/cheng/Environments/proj1_env/bin/python3.8: can't find '__main__' module in ''
```

Also, if I remove the 'runserver' parameter in my config and debug manage.py without a parameter, it does print out the error prompt

> Type 'manage.py help ' for help on a specific subcommand.

- debugger works ok with stable branches like stable/3.2.x

Need some help. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

(SOLVED)
I had the same issue.

Run django fine but if I debugged it can't find '**main**' module in ''

All I had to do was upgrade pycharm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).